# How to solve Inner join Mysql query

Tags: mysql

[image]

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM 
  jobcard jc
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT * 
      FROM jobc_labor
    ) labor  
    ON jc.Jobc_id = labor.RO_no
WHERE 
  labor.status = 'JobDone' 
GROUP BY 
  jc.Jobc_id
```

What I want:

I am using this query on the page where I want to **show user that  jobcards** on which **ALL job/labor were requested are done**. On one jobcard there can be many labor/jobs requested.

The problem is: this query shows me the jobcards on which **even one job/labor are done.**

How can I write a query which returns only those jobcards on which all requested labor/jobs are done?

When a job is entered, by default its status is null. Once it's completed its status changes to jobDone.

Comment: This query is gibberish. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: are there a status for jobc_labor ? how to know all the requested labor.jobs are done ?

Comment: As i mentioned above many labor/jobs can be assigned to single jobc_id. Once any of them are done. user change its status to jobDone from empty field. Now question is how to output those jobc_id on which all job labor status are JobDone.

Comment: can you show sample of your data and how you want the query output ?

Comment: Please don't write words in all-capitals - on the web this is commonly considered to be the same as shouting, and some people will find that rude. I've edited your question to remove that, and tidy up a few other things so it's readable.

Comment: Thank you ADyson :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
SELECT * 
FROM JOBCARD
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID
             FROM JOBS
             GROUP BY ID
             HAVING MIN(STATUS) <> '')
```

Hope this helps.